# Implementations of stochastic collocation for Arbitrage Free SABR

Tags: programming, no-arbitrage-theory, sabr

I am currently reading [this paper (link)](https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=087089099092098125003024125012118005018043040037001065095009015113091102108027095067002010036056019123016100111007091099075022104087070023007104021028066026020099004020076112005124085119124125068126103091109101094015124017077091067022005074072106098&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE) on fitting arbitrage free parameters for SABR using stochastic collocation. Are there any publicly available github repos that implement solutions that are described in this paper? Links would be strongly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for stochastic collocation like this, https://github.com/csdms/dakotathon/blob/master/dakotathon/method/stoch_collocation.py? Or Fitting arbitrage code?